Emptying Cart Commerce 5
I upgraded to commerce 5 from commerce 4 and a simple line of code got broken...
{{ craft.commerce.carts.forgetCart() }}

I used it in the top of my template to make sure the cart is empty when I load the page. I couldn't find the syntax change in the docs...
Any help would be appreciated!!

This method still exists, so I'm not sure what would be causing problems after the migration.
In general, I wouldn't recommend removing the cart cookie on every request, as it will effectively make the cart unusable. Is it possible that the site was previously working in spite of this being in your template?
You can always manually clear a cart for testing with a form like this!

I am aware of the fact that is empties the cart but this was a deliberate need as we don't want users to have the option to buy more than one product at a time. I know we can empty the cart with a form but I wanted it to happen automatically without an action from a user...
